Problem with network bandwidth of Azure App Service (very slow uploads)
My App Service (A) sends a POST request that contains a base64 encoded file to App Service B . I understand that this may seem strange, but it is needed in this case. App Service B uploads it to a Blob Storage and then returns a response. The size of the file is between 40-80mb.
The problem is that the file upload is really slow (sometimes longer than two minutes). I am trying to understand why it is so slow. I would assume that the network bandwith is quite high (the two app services are in the same region). Both app services use the S1 tier.
Here is the simplified code:
App service A Controller:
private static async Task UploadFileToAppServiceB(HttpClient client, string fileName, byte[] fileContent)
{
    var path = $"www.foo.bar/upload";
    var request = new
    {
        FileName = fileName,
        Content = fileContent,
    };
    client.Timeout = TimeSpan.FromMinutes(2);
    var response = await HandleNotFound(client.PostAsJsonAsync(path, request));
    response.EnsureSuccessStatusCode();
}

App Service B controller:
[HttpPost("upload")]
[RequestSizeLimit(209715200)]
public async Task UploadFileToBlobStorage([FromBody] FooFile fooFile)
{
    var fileContent = fooFile.Content;
    var blobContainerClient = GetContainerClient();
    var blobClient = blobContainerClient.GetBlobClient();

    await using var memoryStream = new MemoryStream(fileContent);
    await blobClient.UploadAsync(memoryStream, true);
}

Why does App Service B take so long to respond? Is there a way I can improve this?

Even though both App Services are in the same region, network bandwidth can still be a limiting factor. The S1 tier has limited resources and may not be optimized for handling large file transfers efficiently. Upgrade to a Higher Tier. If network isolation and enhanced performance are critical, consider using an App Service Environment. Use Azure Application Insights to monitor the performance and diagnose issues with your web apps. It can help pinpoint whether the delay is in the network, application code, or storage access.

It's a lengthy process, I'll suggest you the steps. Give it a try-
Upgrade App Service Plan. Change the application to handle binary data directly instead of using base64 as it will reduce the data size and improve transmission speed. App Service A and B Code Modification as below-

For A- `private static async Task UploadFileToAppServiceB(HttpClient client, string fileName, byte[] fileContent)
{
var path = $"https://foo.bar/upload";
using var content = new ByteArrayContent(fileContent);
content.Headers.ContentType = new MediaTypeHeaderValue("application/octet-stream");
var formData = new MultipartFormDataContent
{
{ new StringContent(fileName), "FileName" },
{ content, "file", fileName }
};
var response = await client.PostAsync(path, formData);
response.EnsureSuccessStatusCode();

}`

For B- `[HttpPost("upload")]
[RequestSizeLimit(209715200)]
public async Task UploadFileToBlobStorage(IFormFile file)
{
var blobContainerClient = new BlobServiceClient(connectionString).GetBlobContainerClient("mycontainer");
var blobClient = blobContainerClient.GetBlobClient(file.FileName);
await using (var stream = file.OpenReadStream())
{
    await blobClient.UploadAsync(stream, true);
}
return Ok();

}`

Ensure the existing code above is using async-await properly to not block on I/O operations. Rest as suggested upgrade your Azure Blob Storage to premium and enable Application Insights for Monitoring. Test the upload functionality by sending a file from App Service A to App Service B and monitor the same from app insight. See if this resolves your latency

Hi @Arko, thanks for the help. I checked the blob storage E2E latency metric and it is usually below 1s. I think the problem is somewhere between receiving the file in App Service A and receiving it in App Service 2. I will make the changes you suggested and update here.

Great, I'll post my suggestion as answer here. Thanks

To address the issue of slow uploads between Azure App Services and to Azure Blob Storage, you can follow these steps to optimize the performance.
Upgrade App Service Plan so that can provide additional resources that improve network throughput and overall performance.

Navigate to the Azure Portal.
Go to your App Service.
Click on "Scale up (App Service plan)" under Settings.
Choose a higher-tier plan such as P1V2 or P2V3 and review the additional resources and features they offer.
Click on "Apply" to upgrade your plan.


Modify Application to Handle Binary Data. Changing the application to handle binary data directly instead of using base64 will reduce the data size and improve transmission speed.
*App Service A Code Modification: * Replace the base64 encoding mechanism with a binary data handling approach in your HTTP client request.
private static async Task UploadFileToAppServiceB(HttpClient client, string fileName, byte[] fileContent)
{
    var path = $"https://foo.bar/upload";
    using var content = new ByteArrayContent(fileContent);
    content.Headers.ContentType = new MediaTypeHeaderValue("application/octet-stream");
    var formData = new MultipartFormDataContent
    {
        { new StringContent(fileName), "FileName" },
        { content, "file", fileName }
    };

    var response = await client.PostAsync(path, formData);
    response.EnsureSuccessStatusCode();
}

App Service B Code Modification: Change the controller to accept a file stream directly.
[HttpPost("upload")]
[RequestSizeLimit(209715200)]
public async Task<IActionResult> UploadFileToBlobStorage(IFormFile file)
{
    var blobContainerClient = new BlobServiceClient(connectionString).GetBlobContainerClient("mycontainer");
    var blobClient = blobContainerClient.GetBlobClient(file.FileName);

    await using (var stream = file.OpenReadStream())
    {
        await blobClient.UploadAsync(stream, true);
    }
    return Ok();
}

Enable Asynchronous Processing i.e. ensure the existing code above is using async-await properly to not block on I/O operations.
Optimize Azure Blob Storage Configuration
Switch to a higher-performance tier for Azure Blob Storage if you are using standard storage.

Go to your Storage Account in the Azure Portal.
Navigate to "Configuration" under Settings.
Change the performance tier to Premium


Implement Application Insights for Monitoring
Set up Application Insights for detailed performance monitoring and to identify any other bottlenecks.

Go to the Azure Portal.
Search for Application Insights and create a new resource or attach to an existing App Service.
Follow the instructions to integrate Application Insights with your application.


Add Application Insights SDK to your projects:
dotnet add package Microsoft.ApplicationInsights.AspNetCore 

Configure in Startup.cs:
public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
{
    services.AddApplicationInsightsTelemetry();
    // other services
}

If the end-to-end latency metric for the Blob Storage is below 1 second, the focus should shift to the network and processing efficiency between App Service A and App Service B.
So if you want to check network latency use tools like application insight as suggested above

then suppose if both services are within the same region but not in the same virtual network, consider configuring VNet Integration to potentially reduce latency and enhance security.
These steps will provide a systematic approach to troubleshoot your slow file uploads better.
References:

Upload files in ASP.NET Core
ASP.NET Core Blazor file uploads
Latency in Blob storage


I noticed that after upgrading the SKU of App Service B, the update was about 300% faster (but still too slow). According to someone at Microsoft Q&A, the network bandwith on higher SKUs is higher.
This is not really a solution, so I will change this code to upload the file directly to the blob storage from App Service A.
